# UIDatePicker - DateFormatter is returning the day after the one selected in the picker

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a function that returns the day selected in the

I have this function that is supposed to return the date in the picker as a string but it returns the day after the one selected.. I did a test and the NSDate object seems to be ok. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
func dateformatterDate(date: NSDate) -> NSString
{
    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)


}
```

Comment: Are you taking into account that the NSDate object you pass into the method will be in GMT and not UTC?

Comment: Oh, is GMT supposed to be equivalent to UTC?

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

The problem is that the date picker uses localtime and you are converting it to string using UTC time. Try like this:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let date = DateFormatter()
}
extension Date {
    var customDate: String {
        Formatter.date.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        return Formatter.date.string(from: self)
    }
}

Date().customDate   //  "04-14-2017"
```